# rgbdslam hydro no display

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Has anyone encountered the problem in which rgbdslam does not display as showed in the picture? I am running hydro. Thanks a lot!

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/183242/rgbdslam-hydro-no-display/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2014-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem has been solved by typing $roscore first before typing

$roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch 
$rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam

---

Originally posted by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) with karma: 286 on 2014-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [monkeyiq](https://answers.ros.org/users/20182/monkeyiq/) on 2014-09-18**:
I still only get an empy window as shown in the picture at the top of this thread... pressing enter to start doesn't change things.

In the terminal that runs
$roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

I see a lot of messages TF2 exception Invalid argument "/camera_rgb_optical_frame" passed ...

**Comment by [monkeyiq](https://answers.ros.org/users/20182/monkeyiq/) on 2014-09-18**:
Full single message block:

[ WARN] [1411070495.613534256]: TF2 exception:
Invalid argument "/camera_rgb_optical_frame" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like:

**Comment by [monkeyiq](https://answers.ros.org/users/20182/monkeyiq/) on 2014-09-18**:
This is on 14.04.1 LTS using ROS Indigo.

**Comment by [monkeyiq](https://answers.ros.org/users/20182/monkeyiq/) on 2014-09-18**:
I fixed that by updating the openni launch file and adding a prefix. Then I got images in the rgbdslam GUI!

**Comment by [yoo00](https://answers.ros.org/users/19901/yoo00/) on 2014-10-06**:
I also have the same messages. @monkeyiq, can you give me more details on how to fix this one by adding a prefix?

**Comment by [celston](https://answers.ros.org/users/20401/celston/) on 2014-10-06**:
yooncs8, you need to remove "$(arg tf_prefix)/" from the rgb_frame_id and depth_frame_id parameters in openni.launch.

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-27**:
hi i had the same problem rgbdslam does not displayimage,  i worked with hudro version, ubunto 12.04 and i still have the problem until now, please is there anyone who can help me?

**Comment by [Zari](https://answers.ros.org/users/22203/zari/) on 2015-09-05**:
@celston I already have updated file but it still giving the same error,
e.g.,  

Any idea?